# prototyping a cyclotron , a charging problem

Tags: experimental-physics, charge, experimental-technique

I'd like to model a cyclotron but not with subatomic particles but with a small metallic ball but the problem is i need to charge the metallic ball with certain amount of charge and i must know it to use the equation and find the needed frequency of the alternating voltage
is there any idea to do it precisely ?

Comment: In practice you would detect the movement of the ball across the gap between the plates and tune your excitation frequency with a phase locked loop to that. That is exactly how real accelerators are being operated, too. All frequencies and phases are being constantly tuned to maximize the efficiency of the machine. This is necessary to compensate for mechanical drifts in machine parameters, even though the charge of the particles is constant.

Comment: Perhaps rather than using a metallic ball you could use some sort of dielectric material that could be initially charged with say a Van DeGraff machine and injected using a gas nozzle. Rosin or amber particles come to mind. To keep the design simple you could use the approach first used by Lawrence. He used a single D electrode in the chamber and the tank itself as the other electrode.

Comment: @docscience Lawrence who ?

Comment: So you want to build a cyclotron and don't know who Ernest Lawrence was? Wow.  For youre reference, he invented the cyclotron, and his name remains on both the Lawrence Livermore and Lawrence Berkeley Laboratories.

Comment: Yes! - That's the guy. He also has the honor of having element 103 named after him - Lawrencium. The single D electrode design is on display at the Smithsonian in Washington DC. If I recall the tank diameter was only 4 or 6 inches. I think Lawrence accelerated protons to less than 100 keV.

Comment: The 5200G magnet and 4" cyclotron produced ~80keV protons (December 1930). The cyclotron D's used to be on display at Lawrence Berkeley. The 14kG 9" magnet and matching cyclotron made 900keV protons (June 1931). Making a near replica should be pretty straightforward at this point. As I recall the Rutger's physics department has a student-built cyclotron in operation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the charge can be arbitrary: you can charge your metal ball more or you can charge it less. There are a couple of mechanisms though that limit the charge, such as the strength of the material of the ball.

Comment: How it is arbitrary and the frequency depends on the charge?

Comment: @MohamedOsama: For example, if you charge your metal ball by connecting it to some potential (this is  not the most efficient method, but it's OK as an example), the charge on the ball will depend on the potential. The frequency is proportional to the charge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#Principle_of_operation )

Comment: How i can charge the ball with connecting it to some potential and we have KCL rule that says the charges that enter will leave so i gained nothing ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama: I don't think the standard KCL rule applies to the transient process. The charges will enter until the potentials equalize (the charge will not be very large due to low capacity of the metal ball - as I said, this method is not efficient). Where will they leave, in your opinion?

Comment: i misunderstood you , do you mean we get a battery and get its terminals across the ball ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama: No. Imagine that initially the metal ball is electrically neutral (if it is not, yo can initially ground it, it will become neutral (or close to that). Then you disconnect it from the ground and connect it to a pole of a DC source with high potential V with respect to ground (the other pole of the source can be grounded). Some charge will flow to the ball until it acquires potential V. Then you disconnect the ball from the source. The charge on the metal ball is defined by V and by the capacity of the ball.